# How to fix credentials error - ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to access the credentials in initializers. Before that I am checking in rails console if I can retrieve it, but it gives me the error

I also tried to remove and create new credentials - it creates new credentials and master file, but error remains the same

my code snap

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've not used this feature yet, but it looks like you're adding unencrypted data to an encrypted file.

The correct command is:

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

replacing vim with whatever editor you prefer. You'll need to remove your additions to the file first though...

For more info, try `rails credentials:help`

(Source and more info: https://blog.eq8.eu/til/rails-52-credentials-tricks.html)

Comment: Its Working , Thankyou and yes my default editor is vim already. This is so basic why this isnt mentioned anywhere in documents or any other platform?

Comment: It does, but it's a footnote here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials - it's quite a new feature, and I only found that page thanks to a link on the changelog...